# Grammar and meaning question

Tags: grammar, meaning

Which sentence is correct , Please explain it to me :

sentence 1 : It was dark ,moonlit night when he **arrived** at the inn

sentence 2 : It was dark ,moonlit night when he **had arrived** at the inn

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence with the indefinite article **a** before **dark** would be natural and correct.

You would use the past perfect **had arrived** only in a context when you wish to emphasise that he arrived there before something else occurred. For example:

> He had arrived at the inn early in order to secure a room, only to discover that the inn was full.

The above sentence would also be correct if you omitted **had**. Much of the time, the choice between the past tense and the past perfect is optional.